# Facebook App Can not be published

Tags: android, facebook, share, review

I am using Facebook login and share in my android app.Facebook login is working. While sharing I am getting the following message '(#200)The user hasn't authorized this application to perform this action'.
I am using open graph share for customizing the share view.While submitting the Facebook app, I am getting the following message

[image]

Why this happens?What should i do to overcome this? can anyone please help. What is my mistake?

Comment: i have the same problem.Can anyone please help.

Comment: Have you made any API calls that requires publish_actions the last 30 days? And if so what?

Comment: While i am checking for permissions ,publish permisions is not there. So i added
 Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
      .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
    
    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);But it just navigating to facebook(only a white background) and returns back. I added Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data); in my activity's onActivityResult. Is there anything else to add